# Ordering by query

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to have documents returned in the order they were requested, if using $in and searching for _id? Is there anyway to sort the output by the order in the query?

From the docs, there is an example like this:

db.things.find({j:{$in: [4,2,6]}});

So let's presume we want this query:

db.things.find({_id:{$in: [4,2,6]}});

and the result to be ordered by 4,2,6 (the document ids, in the order in the array in the query).

Comment: Your example, with sort() would bring them back in order ... however would a better example of what you are asking be > db.things.find({_id:{$in : [4,2,6]}}); with the order being returned 4,2,6 instead of 2,4,6?

Answer (score 3):

Some more detail would help ... but [.sort()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-Sorting) should do the trick ...

You can use it in a couple ways, like ORDER BY in SQL ...

Sorting by **FirstName** *descending* (**-1**) ascending would be (**1**) ...

```
> db.myCollection.find().sort({ "FirstName" : 1 });
```

Or using "[natural order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order)" ...

> Natural order" is defined as the
>   database's native ordering of objects
>   in a collection.
>
> When executing a find() with no
>   parameters, the database returns
>   objects in forward natural order.

So ...

```
> db.myCollection.sort({$natural:-1})
```

Ordering by **_id** should take the datetime that is embedded into the **_id** (if using a MongoDB [ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)) into account ...

Answer (score 0):

also can do like this

> db.things.find({_id:{$in: [4,2,6]}}).sort({_id:1});